# Show values of different array types

Tags: java, arrays, outputstream

I have a question about the output of Arrays in Java.
So, when I have this code:

```
char[] chars = new char[] {'a', 'b', 'c'};
System.out.println(chars);
```

Then the output is: `abc`.

I know that an Array is an Object in Java. So I think the `toString()` method will be called here?

But if I have this code:

```
int[] ints = new int[] {3, 4, 5};
System.out.println(ints);
```

Then the output is: `[I@1540e19d`.

Why is the first code working and not the second one?
I know that I can call the static method `toString()` in class `Arrays`, but this not the answer I'm looking for.

Can you help me, why the Java developers using different techniques to show the values of Arrays?

Comment: Because print/println is overloaded to take a char array as parameter and print its content. See the doc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html

Comment: @AlexisC. Please make this an answer, because you're absolutely right. And @Fabian: `Then the output is a reference to this Array Object.` No, it is not the reference, it is a hex version of the objects hash code. But many people miss this detail :).

Comment: Ah okay, but its not absolutely wrong, when I say, it is a reference to this object? Because my book furnished to me :(

Comment: @FabianKönig No, it is wrong. It may look like a memory address  (especially with the *@*), but it isn't one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `println` method overloaded and can accept `char[]`, see its [source - `println(char x[])`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/PrintStream.java#PrintStream.println%28char%5B%5D%29):

```
757 public void println(char x[]) {
758     synchronized (this) {
759         print(x);
760         newLine();
761     }
762 }
```

`print` calls `write(char buf[])` which iterates on the sequence and print it.

Also refer to the docs and see [`PrintStream#println(char[] x)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println-char:A-):

> Prints an array of characters and then terminate the line. This method behaves as though it invokes `print(char[])` and then `println()`.

Comment: THANKS, sorry it was my mistake. I had overlook this :S

Answer (score 4):

Look at the method signatures of the `println` method:

[**println(char [] x**)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println(char[])) exists: 
**The method converts each character into a byte value according to the system's character encoding and prints them all**.

But there does not exist any method, that takes an integer array.

Instead, the generic [**println(Object x)**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println(java.lang.Object)) method is called

Comment: THANKS, sorry it was my mistake. I had overlook this :S